# Python on Server: What does the following error message mean?

Tags: python, server

I have a python that works perfectly fine when I let it run via a 
local python server on my machine. So, I uploaded it on a server,
set the correct permission octals and then tried to access the
.cgi file via the browser.It doesn't run, but I get the following message:

```
The following python binaries are available:

python3: Python 3.7.7

Please use the binary for the version of Python you want.
```

As I am new to Python, I don't know how to interprete this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your cgi file probably has a line at the top that looks something like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
```

Change `python` to `python3`.